# How is Kinetic energy a constant when velocity is a constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

if Kinetic derived from $W = Fd $

$W = mad $

$KE = m\frac{v}{t}vt\frac{1}{2}$

$KE = \frac{1}{2}mv ^{2}$

that means when velocity a constant, acceleration is zero

$KE = m(0)vt = 0 $

Comment: What is the issue? You arrive at KE = (1/2)m.v^2, and its quite clear here that a constant speed (and no change in mass) means constant KE. Haven't you just answered your own question?

Comment: I mean if velocity a constant that means KE = 0, is that true ?

Comment: No. A constant velocity means a constant KE. Not KE=0. Why would you think so, when you have arrived at the expression: KE = (1/2)m.v^2?

Comment: Kinetic energy is **defined** to be $K = 1/2mv^2$ Mass is generally constant, so kinetic energy is constant when velocity is constant.

Comment: @randomrand Constant velocity, zero acceleration, means no additional KE, not zero KE, it still has the KE from it's momentum

Comment: Please format equations in Latex: there is a guide in the forum on how to do it. For now I’ve done it.

Comment: Note that 0 *is* a constant.

Answer (score 2):

> if Kinetic derived from $W = F.s$

(note I've swapped $d$ for $s$)

You are narrowly misinterpreting the work-energy theorem.

It should really read:

$$\text{d}W=F\text{d}s=\text{d}K$$

Or:

$$W=\int_{s_0}^{s_1}F\text{d}s=\frac12 mv_f^2-\frac12 mv_i^2=\Delta K$$

In the case of uniform, linear motion, i.e. $v=\text{cst}=v_i=v_f$ and thus $a=0$, then $F=ma=0$, so that:

$$W=\int_{s_0}^{s_1}0\text{d}s=0=\Delta K$$